# Rewrite at the beginning of the file

Tags: c, linux, gcc

I was trying to rewriting text at beginning of file but facing the following:

The header file is test.h:

```
#ifndef test_h

#define test_h

#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

char auth_xml_val[400];

void generate_auth_xml(FILE *);

#endif
```

The source file is test.c :

```
#include"test.h"

extern int count;

char auth_xml_val[] ="UEQ5NGJXd2dkbVZ5YzJsdmJqMGlNUzR3SWlCbGJtTnZaR2x1WnowaVZWUkdMVGdpSUhOMFlXNWtZV3h2Ym1VOUlubGxjeUkvUGp4QmRYUm9JSFZwWkQw";

void generate_auth_xml(FILE *fp)
{
    char *local= (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(auth_xml_val)+2));
// Removing last chars
    strcpy(local,auth_xml_val);
    local[strlen(auth_xml_val)-1] = '\0';

    //fprintf(fp,"%06d\n",1000);

    count++;
    fprintf(fp,"%s\n",local);       

    count++;
    fprintf(fp,"%s\n","empty");
    free(local);

    fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_SET);
    fprintf(fp, "%d\n",count);
}
```

The main file is main.c:

```
#include"test.h"

int count = 0;

int main()
{

    FILE *fp_test;

    fp_test = fopen("adhaar_auth_xml_test.txt","w+");

    if(fp_test == NULL)
    {
        printf("cannot open file.\n");
        return 0;
    }

    generate_auth_xml(fp_test);

    fclose(fp_test);
    printf("Number of string count : %d\n",count);
    return 0;
}
```

The make file is:

```
all : test.o main.o run

run : test.o main.o
    $(CC) -g $^ -o $@

%.o : %.c
    ${CC} -g -c $< -o $@


.PHONY : clean

clean :
    -rm -f *.o run
```

The out put was expected is:

```
2

    UEQ5NGJXd2dkbVZ5YzJsdmJqMGlNUzR3SWlCbGJtTnZaR2x1WnowaVZWUkdMVGdpSUhOMFlXNWtZV3h2Ym1VOUlubGxjeUkvUGp4QmRYUm9JSFZwWkQ

empty
```

But it is replacing first few characters of the first line.

```
2
    Q5NGJXd2dkbVZ5YzJsdmJqMGlNUzR3SWlCbGJtTnZaR2x1WnowaVZWUkdMVGdpSUhOMFlXNWtZV3h2Ym1VOUlubGxjeUkvUGp4QmRYUm9JSFZwWkQ

empty
```

Where I am going wrong?

Comment: Do not cast the result of `malloc()` here: `char *local= (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(auth_xml_val)+2));` or anywhere.

Comment: Writing at the start overwrites whatever was there... that's normal.  If you want to *insert* characters instead, you have to write the rest of the file again, in the new position after the characters you inserted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output is perfectly normal.

You expect you can *insert* characters at the beginning of the file. This is not possible. Instead your program simply overwrites the first 2 characters of the file hence the output you get.